# Shiny generate random values every time press button

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny and do simple shiny application, which generates iid normal variables and prints histogram. 
The input has:

- 2 numericInput fields, mu and sigma
- ActionButton

Output is tabsetPanel:

- Tab1: 5 generated values
- Tab2: histogram

So it does not work. I tried a lot variants and only insufficiently working solution was this.

Here is code ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(xtable)

meanInput1 <- numericInput("id1", "$$mean \\ of \\ x_1$$", 1, min = -10, max = 10, step = 1)
meanInput2 <- numericInput("id2", "$$sd \\ of \\ x_2$$", 1, min = -10, max = 10, step = 1)
tabPanel1 <- tabPanel("generated values", tableOutput("table1"))
tabPanel2 <- tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot1"))

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    withMathJax(),
    titlePanel("title"),

    sidebarLayout(
        fluid=TRUE,

        sidebarPanel(
            meanInput1,
            meanInput2,
            actionButton("goButton", "Go!")
        ),
    mainPanel(

        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel1,
            tabPanel2
        )
    )
)))
```

Here is code server.R

```
shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {

        output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
            if (input$goButton >= 1){
                sigma <- input$id2
                muInput <- input$id1

                table <- as.data.frame(rnorm(n = 5,muInput,sd = sigma))
                names(table) <- "x"

                output$plot1 <- renderPlot(hist(table));
                output$table1 <- renderTable(head(table));
            }
        })
    }
)
```

Questions:

- It works only if buttonClicked **once** and tabPanel2 is selected. How to make it work every time I click a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `eventReactive` in this case.  You can find demos for using the `actionButton` [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/actionbutton-demo.html).  You also have somewhat strange structure to your code with render statements inside of render statements.

If you create your `eventReactive` function and separate out your `renderTable` and `renderPlot` calls it is much clearer and works correctly.  It is also good practice to not name variables the same as functions so I changed the `table` variables to `my_table` for clarity.

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) {

    rand <- eventReactive(input$goButton,{
      sigma <- input$id2
      muInput <- input$id1

      my_table <- as.data.frame(rnorm(n = 5,muInput,sd = sigma))
      names(my_table) <- "x"
      return(my_table)
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      my_table <- rand()
      if(is.null(my_table)){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        hist(head(my_table$x));
      }
    })


    output$table1 <- renderTable({
      my_table <- rand()

      if(is.null(my_table)){
        return(NULL)
      }else{
        my_table
      }
    });
  }
)
```